# Integrate ambient data Framework with Java Application

Tags: smarttarget, ambient-data-framework

I am trying to install Ambient Data Framework on my Java Application for SmartTarget 2014 SP1 implementation. I have followed the steps from the the manual: [Setting up the Ambient Data Framework in a Java Web application](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202013%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-7C29E193-D3BB-48FA-B3C1-01D5140D2B44)  {Login Required}

When I restart my Tomcat Server after deploying the required Jar Files and xml files, it shows an error cannot connect to Fredhopper and Error fetching Trigger Types from Fredhopper. The Fredhopper instance and my website are deployed on different servers. So, where in the Ambient Data configuration files do I have to give the address of my Fredhopper instance. I could not find anything in cd_ambient_conf.xml and smarttartget_conf.xml files etc.

Kindly provide some pointers for the same.

Thanks and Regards,
Mark Thomas

Comment: I changed the documentation link to a more persistent (and shorter) url.

Comment: It helps if you can post the error message.

Answer (score 3):

If the there is an Fredhopper error for fetching the Trigger Types from Fredhopper then ADF is working and you have an issue in the SmartTarget cartrdige which is added to ADF.

**ADF config**

In ADF's `cd_ambient_conf.xml` you have enabled this cartrdige

```
<Cartridge File="smarttarget_cartridge_conf.xml" />
```

**SmartTarget config**

The SmartTarget cartridge uses in turn the SmartTartget configuration in `smarttarget_conf.xml`. This configuration file specifies the Fredhopper endpoint.

There are several Fredhopper instances in this cofiguration file. Have a look at the endpoint in the `IndexServer\Url` element, check if this Fredhopper instance is up and running.

```
    <IndexServer>
        <Url>http://localhost:8180/</Url>
        <Authentication>
            <Username>admin</Username>
            <Password>...</Password>
        </Authentication>
        ...
    </IndexServer>
```

**Fredhopper endpoint**

Try `http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/config/trigger-types` on the Fedhopper indexer instance to check if you have configured the right IndexServer URL, this should give you an XML document with the Trigger types like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<trigger-types xmlns="http://www.fredhopper.com/schema/knowledge-model/trigger/type/1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.fredhopper.com/schema/knowledge-model/trigger/operation/1.0" xmlns:ns3="http://www.fredhopper.com/schema/knowledge-model/trigger/basetype/1.0" xmlns:ns4="http://www.fredhopper.com/schema/knowledge-model/trigger/1.0">
    <trigger-type basetype="number" url-param="sc_session_lifetime" name="Session - Length"/>
    <trigger-type basetype="histogram" url-param="fh_histogram" name="fh_histogram"/>
    <trigger-type basetype="text" url-param="st_region" name="SmartTarget Region">
        <list-of-values>
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks Jan for the response. I have got the issue resolved now. I was due to the application server not able to connect to the Fredhopper server.

Comment: I have my front end as a Java application, how will ADF talk to tridion and run the Fredhopper queries to render content based on rules configured in Fredhopper. Do I need to write a code at JSP page level? Kindly provide some pointers.Thanks

Comment: @MarkThomas: good question! I answered it: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8554/how-do-i-to-run-smarttarget-on-a-java-web-application/8555#8555