# How do I to run SmartTarget on a Java web application?

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I have my front end as a Java application, how will ADF talk to Tridion and run the Fredhopper queries to render content based on rules configured in Fredhopper? Do I need to write a code at JSP page level? Kindly provide some pointers.

*This question is taken from [this comment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8430/integrate-ambient-data-framework-with-java-application/8433?noredirect=1#comment11873_8433). Originally asked by [Mark Thomas](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/1283/mark-thomas).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JAVA website will use the SmartTaget tag library, or if you like the SmartTarget API, to get the content for a specific SmartTarget region. SmartTarget will also take care of the SmartTarget markup for Experience Manager.

In a JSP page you could add some JSP tags to define the SmartTarget region on the page. SmartTarget will do the rest. See a [minimal JSP example](https://gist.github.com/0b313b9d0fb1b3eb1f2b), [full JSP example](https://gist.github.com/83e45c851b63481e39bb), also the [Dreamweaver templating](https://gist.github.com/6053b09d0ccbd31e058b) and [TCDL](https://gist.github.com/3b5c48c3a5ea5d5e12b8) equivalent. The [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-0047C784-2FC3-4402-B403-AB2DB081AC44) (login required) explains a lot of detail as well.

The SmartTarget libraries will then form a Fredhopper query and execute it. A helper in the SmartTarget API takes claims (variables) from ADF and maps them to Fredhopper triggers (the mapping is configured in the smarttarget_conf.xml on the website webapp).

So **ADF** does not talk to **Fredhopper**. The role of ADF is to gather the user context variables named **claims**. **SmartTarget** will take this data, figure out which **triggers** have to be set on the Fredhopper **query**, and execute this query.

*Off-topic but nice to know:* In SmartTarget 2014 SP1 the SmartTarget API is very open, for example, you change the Fredhopper query before it gets executed, change the triggers which were mapped from ADF and more.

Comment: Hi Jan, I have gone through the above links. My doubt is as follows:

Comment: Hi Jan,  I have gone through the above links. My doubt is as follows: For our case, we are generating the page XML where content is stored as CDATA tags and storing it in a Broker Database. The content is displayed on the webpage by a JSF Java Application which consumes the generated XML from Broker Database through a Content Service Layer by using Web Services. How will the Java Application invoke the Fredhopper queries and display content based on ADF claims.. What API can I use and what parameters I need to pass to Tridion/Smart Target to acheive the functionality. Thanks